# How to fetch data with infinite scroll and implement search with filters in React using Axios?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, scroll, pagination

How can I do a search if I have an infinite scroll on the page? Axios request displays 10 posts for me, at the moment when I "view" the 10th post, it gives me 10 more posts. So, I have a search string and a few more parameters by which I want to filter when receiving posts from the server. How is it possible to implement it? In short, I want that if the search string or one of the checkboxes was empty, then all the posts in a row were displayed to me, and if any of this is filled, then the posts were displayed exactly according to these criteria.

Here is the code I have at the moment:

```
 const [limit, setLimit] = useState(10);
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  const [fetching, setFetching] = useState(true);
  const [text, setText] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    if(fetching){
      console.log('fetching');
      axios.get(`http://localhost:3500/api/posts?limit=${limit}`)
      .then(response => {
      setData(response.data.values)
      setLimit(prevState => prevState + 10)
    })
    .finally(() => setFetching(false));
    }
  }, [fetching])
  useEffect(() => {
    document.addEventListener('scroll', scrollHandler)
    return function(){
      document.removeEventListener('scroll', scrollHandler)
    }
  })


  const scrollHandler = (e) => {
    if(e.target.documentElement.scrollHeight - (e.target.documentElement.scrollTop + window.innerHeight) < 100){
      console.log('scroll');
      setFetching(true);
    }
  }


return (
 <>
  {data.map(result => {
    <span>{result.name}</span>
    <span>{result.text}</span>
    <span>{result.category}</span>
    <span>{result.date}</span>
  })}
 </>
);
```